# After installing each Sdk Api that missing and gradle can not build

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

I new to android studio.I download android studio then install it. and download sdk-tools and sdk-platform. then extraxt those in same folder and pass it to android studio as sdk file.

after open sdk manager in android studio. an select each api to download. after finish installing and download that checkbox dont check.[image]

in same time the gradle can not build and have `Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown` error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gradle syncing requires an internet connection, though by your screenshot you seem to be connected.

You can also try invalidating your cache: File > Press Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Or if are using a proxy server, disable it and try again.

Comment: the internet connection is good. and use Invalidate Caches/Restart don't help me.